# DataWeave XML transform (list unique nested elements)

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have below xml and need to transform it  using mule data weave transformation.

```
<Colleges>
  <College>
    <name>C1</name>
    <Students>
      <Student>
        <name>s1</name>
        <dept>d1</dept>
      </Student>
      <Student>
        <name>s2</name>
        <dept>d2</dept>
      </Student>
      <Student>
        <name>s3</name>
        <dept>d3</dept>
      </Student>
      <Student>
        <name>s4</name>
        <dept>d3</dept>
      </Student>
    </Students>
  </College>
</Colleges>
```

I want to transform it to below xml by getting unique departments from above xml.

```
<Departments>
  <name>d1</name>
  <name>d2</name>
  <name>d3</name>
</Departments>
```

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
Departments: payload.Colleges.College.Students.*Student mapObject (
    name: $.dept
) distinctBy $.name
```

Post the example payload to localhost:8081/

```
    <flow name="departments">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
Departments: payload.Colleges.College.Students.*Student mapObject (
    name: $.dept
) distinctBy $.name]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
    </flow>
```

Comment: This won't work for a couple of reasons. First, `.*Student` returns an array, and `mapObject` expects an object. Second, `distinctBy $.name` will fail because `$.name` will return null (you're skipping over `Departments`).

Comment: @jerney I humbly ask you to try the dataweave provided with the sample request and expected output provided in the question. It works.

Comment: You're right! My apologies. I think 1.0 does some array/object coercion that I was forgetting about.

Comment: I'm pretty excited for dw 2.0 when our company makes the switch. It's one thing that many questions don't include. Thanks!

Comment: Not at all relevant to Stack Overflow... but If you follow the Online Mule Meetup group: https://meetups.mulesoft.com/online-group/, I'll be doing a talk on DW 2.0 in the beginning of November. Seems like you know what you're doing by maybe others at your company could benefit!

Comment: It'd be nice if they posted that in the "Upcoming Events". :(

Comment: The even organizer and I just started talking about this yesterday. You're the first to know LOL.

Comment: ha! that's fair. thanks in advance for sharing your knowledge!